# How to remove all the items from an array in an Optional Java Object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have a many2many relationship between Post and Tag (Topic) Entities. So before I can delete a Post I need to get it, delete its Tags and Topics, save the Post and then delete it, but I cannot find the way to go through the Post Object and remove the Tags and Topics items, if there are any.

I get a: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null

```
@Override
public void delete(Long id) {
    log.debug("Request to delete Post : {}", id);
    Optional<Post> postOpt = postRepository.findById(id);
    Post post = postOpt.get();
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + post);
    for (Tag tag : post.getTags()) {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + tag.toString());
        post.removeTag(tag);
    }
    for (Topic topic : post.getTopics()) {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + topic.toString());
        post.removeTopic(topic);
    }
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + post);
//        postRepository.deleteById(id);
//        postSearchRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

Where the DTO object is like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "publicationDate": "2019-01-07T10:24:15.892Z",
    "quote": "string",
    "tags": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "tagName": "string"
      }
    ],
    "topics": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "topicName": "string"
      }
    ],
    "userId": 0,
  }
]
```

Remove methods in POST:

```
    public Set<Tag> getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public Post tags(Set<Tag> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
    return this;
}

public Post addTag(Tag tag) {
    this.tags.add(tag);
    tag.getPosts().add(this);
    return this;
}

public Post removeTag(Tag tag) {
    this.tags.remove(tag);
    tag.getPosts().remove(this);
    return this;
}

public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}

public Set<Topic> getTopics() {
    return topics;
}

public Post topics(Set<Topic> topics) {
    this.topics = topics;
    return this;
}

public Post addTopic(Topic topic) {
    this.topics.add(topic);
    topic.getPosts().add(this);
    return this;
}

public Post removeTopic(Topic topic) {
    this.topics.remove(topic);
    topic.getPosts().remove(this);
    return this;
}
```

Remove methods in Tags:

```
public Set<Post> getPosts() {
    return posts;
}

public Tag posts(Set<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
    return this;
}

public Tag addPost(Post post) {
    this.posts.add(post);
    post.getTags().add(this);
    return this;
}

public Tag removePost(Post post) {
    this.posts.remove(post);
    post.getTags().remove(this);
    return this;
}

public void setPosts(Set<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}
```

Thanks

AFTER CHANGES: It works.

```
    @Override
public void delete(Long id) {
    log.debug("Request to delete Post : {}", id);

    Optional<Post> postOpt = postRepository.findById(id);
    Post post = postOpt.get();

    ArrayList<Tag> arrayTags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
    arrayTags.addAll(post.getTags());
    Iterator<Tag> copyOfTags = arrayTags.iterator();
    while (copyOfTags.hasNext()) {
        Tag tag = copyOfTags.next();
        tag.removePost(post);
    }

    ArrayList<Topic> arrayTopics = new ArrayList<Topic>();
    arrayTopics.addAll(post.getTopics());
    Iterator<Topic> copyOfTopics = arrayTopics.iterator();
    while (copyOfTopics.hasNext()) {
        Topic topic = copyOfTopics.next();
        topic.removePost(post);
    }

    postRepository.save(post);

    postRepository.deleteById(id);
    postSearchRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

Thanks again and sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: What is the line number you get an exception? Also is your DTO really matters?

Comment: looks like you have a bad configuration on your entities because you might just remove Post entity and entities which are dependent must be removed. can you post your models?

Comment: Please post your 'remove' methods or full entity classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not iterate the Colletion and at the same time removing the elements from the collection.

You want to remove the tags and the topics via the methods **removeTag** and **removeTopic**, so you dont want to use **iterate.remove** method.

Best for you would be to create the copy of the tag collection, and iterate over the copied collection.

```
Set<Tag> copyOfTags = new HashSet<Tag>(post.getTags());
 for (Tag tag : copyOfTags) {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + tag.toString());
        post.removeTag(tag);
    }
```

Comment: how your answer is different then the one I have given using `Arrays.asList`. In you case you are assuming its SET and I am assuming `LIST`?

Comment: Check the api of asList() method, asList method doesnt create the copy of collection. It will create the list with one element that will be Set.

Comment: @SafeVarargs
    @SuppressWarnings("varargs")
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
        return new ArrayList<>(a);
    }

Comment: This will not create the copy of the set. It will return  List<Set<Tag>> it will not return List<Tag>. So you are not able to iterate it like (Tag t: toListReturn) .Do you see what i mean?

Comment: Set is only an example. getTags method returns the collection, because he is able to iterate over that return. SO toList will return the List with one elemetnt that will be the returned collection from the toList method. You were expecting that toList method will return the List with the elements from the collection that is returned by the getTags, and this is wrong assumption.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null  error {Exception in com.jhipsterpress.web.service.impl.PostServiceImpl.delete() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'null'} (that I explain above in AFTER CHANGES). Sorry for the inconvenience. I very much appreciate your help (both). Thanks